# Python - Printing a list of lists with strings inbetween

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that will take a list of lists and print them out one by one with the word UNION between them. My code looks like this:

```
def printsql(lst):
    print("INSERT INTO table")
    for x in lst:
        print("SELECT")
        print(*x, sep=', ')
        print("UNION")
    return(str)

a = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7], [3, 4, 6]]

print(printsql(a))
```

My output currently looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO table
SELECT
1, 3, 4
UNION
SELECT
2, 5, 7
UNION
SELECT
3, 4, 6
UNION
```

This is almost exactly what I need but I can't figure out how to not print the last "UNION". Can someone advise?

Comment: It works fine when I run it.

Comment: Aside from this being a duplicate, `return(str)` in this code makes absolutely no sense, and neither does the `print` in `print(printsql(a))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove the last union and class str

```
   def printsql(lst):
        print("INSERT INTO table")
        counter = 0
        for x in lst:
                counter = counter + 1
                print("SELECT")
                print(*x, sep=', ')
                if (len(lst)- 1) > counter:
                        print("UNION")
        return("")

a = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7], [3, 4, 6]]

print(printsql(a))
```

Comment: This is a quick and easy solution.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks so much

Comment: Why the `return(str)`? When you print the returned value you get `<class 'str'>` from an empty `str` object.

Comment: I fix the class "str" return value can you remove your down vote to the code now.

Comment: Well, enumerate is more elegant than counter, but this works fine, too!

Answer (score 3):

The brute force is to use enumerate

```
for idx, x in enumerate(lst):
  #other stuff#
  if idx<(len(lst) - 1):
    print("UNION")
```

But I’d be interested to see if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: I think adding a repeating pattern at the front of strings just screams .join() like dwag did, but I find this answer to be more readable and simple! Good stuff!

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the `.join` method in Python to insert a string between list elements.

Works like so:

```
>>> '|'.join(['a','b','c','d'])
'a|b|c|d'
```

Your example is essentially doing this:

```
[Header string "INSERT INTO table\nSELECT\n"]
'\nUNION\nSELECT\n'.join([list items])
', '.join([sub list items])
```

To get the pattern you describe.

You can take that description and translate to Python:

```
def printsql(lst):
    s="INSERT INTO table\nSELECT\n"
    s+="\nUNION\nSELECT\n".join(', '.join(str(e) for e in sl) for sl in lst)
    return s
```

Then:

```
>>> a = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7], [3, 4, 6]]
>>> print(printsql(a))
INSERT INTO table
SELECT
1, 3, 4
UNION
SELECT
2, 5, 7
UNION
SELECT
3, 4, 6
```

The general outline is:

1. Create the header with `s="INSERT INTO table\nSELECT\n"`;
2. Use a nested `join` to create the list of lists format of `"\nUNION\nSELECT\n"` between the outer list elements and `', '` with the inner list elements;
3. Return the string to be printed or used in another section of the program.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way avoiding an extra looping and condition:

```
def printsql(lst):
    print("INSERT INTO table")
    for x in lst[:-1]:
        print("SELECT")
        print(*x, sep=', ')
        print("UNION")
    print("SELECT")
    print(*lst[-1], sep=', ')
    return(str)

a = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7], [3, 4, 6]]

print(printsql(a))

'''
INSERT INTO table
SELECT                                                      
1, 3, 4                                                     
UNION                                                      
SELECT                                                      
2, 5, 7                                                     
UNION                                                       
SELECT                                                     
3, 4, 6                                                    
<class 'str'>                                               
'''
```

Comment: That’s elegant and readable! Dawg's answer is also good, but I find the python style of putting loads of things on one line difficult to follow/generate.

Comment: @Pam thank you. I find yours the best of the five and should have been accepted as answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty.

```
def printsql(lst):
    print("INSERT INTO table")
    for x in lst:
            if x != lst[-1]:
                 print("SELECT")
                 print(*x, sep=', ')
                 print("UNION")
            else:
                print("SELECT")
                print(*x, sep=', ')

    return(str)

a = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7], [3, 4, 6]]

print(printsql(a))
```

Comment: Does this assume a list of unique strings? That is, if all the strings in the list are identical, will it work?

Comment: It assume the final value is unique.
Safer route would be
 if x is lst[-1]